# what is the fast fourier transform of complex guassian?

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

It is widely known that Fourier transform of complex Guassian function \begin{equation}
\mathcal \ F(x)=e^{-j x^2/a} 
\end{equation}
 is 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal \ F(f)= A e^{jπ^2f^2a} 
\end{equation}

It is clear that both the function and its Fourier transform have constant  absolute value. That is 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal \ |F(x)|=1 \  \ \  \  \ \    \ for \  all \   \  x 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal \ |F(f)|=A \  \ \  \  \ \    \ for \  all \   \  f 
\end{equation}

Now the problem is when I calculate the Fourier transform of $F(x)$ in Matlab using matlab command fft and I plot absolute value of $ |F(f)|\   vs \ f $ using function $abs(F(f))$. 
Instead of getting a constant value, I get a function which decays on either side (picture attached).

Is there something wrong in my logic?

[Absolute value of Fourier transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDnCo.jpg)

> %%% Matlab code %%%
>   clc
>   clear all
>   L=2e-2;
>   a=1e-6;
>   npix=1024;
>   Fs=(npix-1)/(L);
>   x=L*(-0.5:1/(npix-1):0.5);
>   fx=Fs*(-0.5:1/(npix-1):0.5);
>   I=exp(-1j*(x.^2)/(a));
>   FI=fftshift(fft(I)/npix);
>   cFI=exp(-1j*(pi^2)*(fx.^2)*a);
>   plot(x,imag(I))
>   figure
>   plot(x,abs(I))
>   figure
>   plot(fx,imag(FI),'m')
>   figure
>   plot(fx,abs(FI),'m')